# Placing input field and button in center of the screen

Tags: flutter

I want to have simple input field with button below it and I am trying to put it in the center of the screen.

This is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white10),
      child: new Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder())),
            IconButton(
             icon: Icon(Icons.volume_up),
             tooltip: 'Increase volume by 10%',
             onPressed: () { setState(() { _volume *= 1.1; }); },)

          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

However it goes to the top of the screen even though I use `Center()` widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you want is center vertically, using `mainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisAlignment`

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white10),
      child: new Center(
        child: Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
           children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder())),
            IconButton(
             icon: Icon(Icons.volume_up),
             tooltip: 'Increase volume by 10%',
             onPressed: () { setState(() { _volume *= 1.1; }); },)

          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought Center widget does it automatically.